# Declaring a cursor inside sql stored procedure goes 'success with compilation errors' every time. Is my syntax wrong? I am using Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures, oracle11g, cursor

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deptShow (tempCID IN VARCHAR2) IS

CURSOR temp_cursor IS SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_ID dept_id, D.DEPARTMENT_NAME dept_name

FROM DEPARTMENTS D
JOIN LOCATIONS L ON (D.LOCATION_ID=L.LOCATION_ID)
JOIN COUNTRIES C ON (L.COUNTRY_ID=C.COUNTRY_ID)

WHERE C.COUNTRY_ID=tempCID;



BEGIN

FOR temp_row IN temp_cursor 

    LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(temp_row.dept_id||temp_row.dept_name);
    END LOOP;


END;
```

Comment: I was running queries under hr schema.

Comment: What does `select * from user_errors;` give you? That's usually enough to work out what's gone wrong.